# Hive (or MySQL): Finding event of different type with maximum timestamp

Tags: mysql, database, hive

I am trying to write a hive query where I am interested in the relationship between two different even types that are in the same table.  For example, say my table is built like this:

```
event_type     timestamp             source
completion     2013-03-04 12:00:55   NULL
completion     2013-03-04 11:55:55   NULL
impression     2013-03-04 11:53:45   A
impression     2013-03-04 11:57:55   A
impression     2013-03-04 11:58:00   B
```

For every completion, I would like to grab the timestamp of the most recent impression, and its source.  For example, what I would hope to get out of a query on the above sample would be:

```
completion_timestamp    most_recent_impression    source
2013-03-04 12:00:55     2013-03-04 11:58:00       B
2013-03-04 11:55:55     2013-03-04 11:53:45       A
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

This relies on times being unique. You should probably add an id column to get around that.

The subquery gets each completion time (`GROUP BY c.ts`) and the latest impression time (`MAX(i.ts)`) that was before the completion time (`i.ts < c.ts`).

```
SELECT
  completionTime, impressionTime, s.source
FROM
(SELECT
  c.ts AS completionTime, MAX(i.ts) AS impressionTime
FROM t AS c
JOIN t AS i
WHERE c.event_type = 'completion'
AND i.event_type = 'impression'
AND i.ts < c.ts -- impressions happen before completions
GROUP BY c.ts) AS t2
JOIN t AS s ON s.ts = t2.impressionTime
ORDER BY completionTime DESC
```

Good ole [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b65c3/18)